# tFuzzyMatch apparently not working on Arabic text strings

Tags: arabic, talend, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison, data-quality

I have created a job in talend open studio for data integration v5.5.1.

I am trying to find matches between two customer names columns, one is a lookup and the other contain dirty data.

The job runs as expected when the customer names are in english. However, for arabic names, only exact matches are found regardless of the underlying match algorithm i used (levenschtein, metaphone, double metaphone) even with loose bounds for the levenschtein algorithm min 1 max 50).

I suspect this has to do with character encoding. How should I proceed? any way I can operate using the unicode or even UTF-8 interpretation in Talend?

I am using excel data sources through tFileInputExcel

Comment: Do you have any example data for me to use? I don't know Arabic so can't think what might have a short edit distance for Levenshtein. Metaphone is an algorithm around English pronunciation so will not work correctly for non English words and won't work at all for non Latin characters.

Comment: I got it resolved by moving the data to mysql with a UTF-8 collation. Somehow Excel input wasn't preserving the collation. Thanks

Comment: Excel is horrible for character sets. It just assumes everything is your default character set so is quite often set to Windows 1252 or some other ASCII extended character set.

Comment: Also consider writing up an answer to your own question and answering it when the timer allows you to. This might help anyone else with this issue in the future. You'd also want edit the question to more accurately describe how you are loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by moving the data to mysql with a UTF-8 collation. Somehow Excel input wasn't preserving the collation.